# How can I get a similar chapter style in the report class?

Tags: chapters, thesis, report

I'm relatively new to LaTeX, and I'm trying to find the right style for my PhD thesis. I want something simple and elegant, inspired by the layout of some books published by Oxford University Press.

Specifically, my goal is to get a chapter style that looks like this (including the chapter title style, the quote and if possible the indented section title style):

[image: My ideal chapter style]

I know that some of this can be done with the titlesec package in principle. However, I'm at a loss when it comes to actually writing to the corresponding code. I've tried to provide a MWE, but in that case I'm really not sure where to begin.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to go:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lf]{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[newlinetospace]{titlesec}%

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\fontsize{30pt}{36pt}\selectfont\filright}{\fontsize{36pt}{48pt}\bfseries\thechapter}{2ex}{}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}

\chapter{The History of the Seven Families \\ of the Lake Pipple-Popple}

       In former days -- that is to say, once upon a time, there lived in the Land of Gramblamble, Seven Families. They lived by the side of the great Lake Pipple-popple (one of the Seven Families, indeed, lived in the Lake), and on the outskirts of the City of Tosh, which, excepting when it was quite dark, they could see plainly. The names of all these places you have probably heard of, and you have only not to look in your Geography books to find out all about them.

       Now the Seven Families who lived on the borders of the great Lake Pipple-popple, were as follows in the next Chapter.

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Added*: if you want for the title a wider right margin (than that of the text), you can add a `\parbox{some width}` s the very last argument of `\titleformat`, like this:

```
 \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\fontsize{30pt}{36pt}\selectfont\filright}{\fontsize{36pt}{48pt}\bfseries\thechapter}{2ex}{\parbox{0.75\textwidth}}
```

[image]

Comment: That's amazing, thank you so much! One small thing: would you know how to reduce the margins of the title (and the epigraph), as in the example I provided? And speaking of the epigraph, do you have a suggestion about the snippet of code I could use for that? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean have shorter margins for the title as compared to the margins  of the document? As to the epigraph, you have Robert Wilson's excellent `epigraph` package (maybe you already used it?).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. I've found plenty of information to change the spacing before/after the title, but not the left/right spacing. Thanks, I'll check out the epigraph package!

Comment: For the title margin problem, please see my update,

Comment: Thank you Bernard! Is it possible at all to do the same with the left margin of the title, as in the example I provided?

Comment: Yes: you can use a `\parbox` of the width you please (a fraction of `\textwidth`)  and replace `\filright` with `\filcenter`.

Comment: Thanks again! However, with `\filcenter`, the chapter number is centered, and most importantly the chapter title is justified, which leads to something that's not very aesthetically pleasing. Sorry for the hassle - would you have a fix for this? To be clear, my goal is to have margins on each side (identical to the margins of the epigraph) while aligning the chapter number & tile to the left. Many thanks in advance! You've already helped me a lot.

Comment: Could you post a minimal *compilable* code of what you've tried (with the epigraph). To have the chapter number not centred, put `\filcenter` at the beginning of the last argument, before `\parbox`.

Comment: Hi Bernard, thanks - I think I fixed it by playing with `\hspace`!

Comment: This is not the simplest solution, as it involves some trial and error, which you'll have to redo if you modify any parameter in your layout. To have a  title of the same width as the epigraph, you can use a `\filcenter\parbox{\epigraphwidth}` as the last argument of `\titleformat`.

Answer (score 1):

The `memoir` class, which encompasses the `book`, `report` and `article` classes and extends them provides some 29 different chapter styles; unfortunately your desired style is not among them but perhaps you would like one of those provided. If not then in the manual (`> texdoc memoir`) code is given for many of these and you could make your own.

The class also provides for epigraphs which you want to put after the chapter title.

For indenting the `section` title the class provides the macro `\setsecindent{<length>}` for setting the indent before section titles.